# How to fix a Div to top of page with CSS only

Tags: html, css

I am writing a glossary page. I have the alphabet links on the top of the page. I want to keep the top of the page (including the alphabet links) fixed, whilst the section of the page with the definitions, scrolls up/down as an alphabet is clicked.

My HTML looks a bit like this:

```
<html>
<head><title>My Glossary</title></head>
<body>
        <div id="top">
            <a href="#A">A</a> |
             <a href="#B">B</a> |
            <a href="#Z">Z</a>
        </div>

        <div id="term-defs">
           <dl>
               <span id="A"></span>
               <dt>foo</dt>
               <dd>This is the sound made by a fool</dd>
               <!-- and so on ... -->
           </dl>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**[Edit]**

The kind of effect I am trying to create is similar to the one [here](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/index.html). The difference being that in the example in the link, the page scrolling is done when a user clicks on a category. In my case, I want to scroll the page when an index (i.e. an alphabet) at the top of the page, is clicked.

Answer (score 95):

Yes, there are a number of ways that you can do this.  The "fastest" way would be to add CSS to the div similar to the following

```css
#term-defs {
    height: 300px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

This will force the div to be scrollable, but this might not get the best effect.  Another route would be to absolute fix the position of the items at the top, you can play with this by doing something like this.

```css
#top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 23px;
}
```

This will fix it to the top, on top of other content with a height of 23px.

The final implementation will depend on what effect you really want.

Comment: just clarifying in case the OP doesn't know, `z-index` is the magic here. It lifts the div "above" the other items on the page and let's them scroll under and "past" it.

Comment: @mitchel: thanks for your help. I tried it, but the effect was not quite what I was looking for. I have edited my question to perhaps explain more clearly, the sort of effect I am trying to achieve - hopefully in a CSS only solution (maybe its not possible?)

Comment: @oompahloompah: The best way to achieve the behavior you desire is to use 'Mitchel Sellers' answer and implement the topbar like `<link rel="import" href="/path/to/topbar.html">`. Another approach would be to add a 'placeholder' div on each site, which should have the same 'height' attribute as the #top element.
Both variations need a slightly adaption to your html code, therefore a wouldn't know about a pure css solution.

Answer (score 18):

You can do something like this:

```
<html>
<head><title>My Glossary</title></head>
<body style="margin:0px;">
        <div id="top" style="position:fixed;background:white;width:100%;">
            <a href="#A">A</a> |
             <a href="#B">B</a> |
            <a href="#Z">Z</a>
        </div>

        <div id="term-defs" style="padding-top:1em;">
           <dl>
               <span id="A"></span>
               <dt>foo</dt>
               <dd>This is the sound made by a fool</dd>
               <!-- and so on ... ->
           </dl>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's the **position:fixed** that's most important, because it takes the top div from the normal page flow and fixes it at it's pre-determined position. It's also important to use the **padding-top:1em** because otherwise the term-defs div would start right under the top div. The **background** and **width** are there to cover the contents of the term-defs div as they scroll under the top div.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do you decide if padding-top would be 1em or more?

Comment: It's actually the height of the item(s) you want fixed at the top. In this case it was 1em because the fixed <div> is one line of text.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply make the top div fixed:

```
#top { position: fixed; top: 20px; left: 20px; }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use **flexbox**, but you'd have to add a parent div that covers `div#top` and `div#term-defs`. So the **HTML** looks like this:

```css
    #content {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    #term-defs {
        flex-grow: 1;
        overflow: auto;
    }
```

```html
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="top">
                <a href="#A">A</a> |
                <a href="#B">B</a> |
                <a href="#Z">Z</a>
            </div>
    
            <div id="term-defs">
                <dl>
                    <span id="A"></span>
                    <dt>foo</dt>
                    <dd>This is the sound made by a fool</dd>
                    <!-- and so on ... -->
                </dl>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

`flex-grow` ensures that the div's size is equal to the remaining size.

You could do the same without flexbox, but it would be more complicated to work out the height of `#term-defs` (you'd have to know the height of `#top` and use `calc(100% - 999px)` or set the height of `#term-defs` directly).
With flexbox dynamic sizes of the divs are possible.

One difference is that the scrollbar only appears on the `term-defs div`.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution for fixed div not overlapping with siblings

If you want your div to be fixed but don't want to overlap with the siblings
use `position: sticky` and `top: 0px` for your fixed header. With this, the div will be fixed and also takes its height from the parent so the siblings won't overlap with the fixed div.

```css
.parent {
  height: 50vh;
  overflow: auto;
  background: yellow;
}

.fixed {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background: pink;
}

.content {
  height: 150vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
     <div class="fixed">
        Fixed Header
     </div>
     <div class="content">
        <p>content</p>
     </div>
</div>
```