# how to create horizontal drop-down menu with javascript for asp.net website?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css, drop-down-menu

i am developing i website using **master page** this master page doesn't has any menus but i want to create a javascript menu for one of the **content page** and this page will navigate to other pages the will have the same menu always appeared there.

i am using c# and asp.net so how to do that and make this menu also fixed among all selected items (and see which one selected by some css) .

i hope that i described well what i need because i am so confused so sorry for that.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand your question...

Comment: sorry for that look i need a menu that will appear only in one of the content page i mean this content page will take the style of the master page +new menu that will appear only there (we can consider at this time this content page as another master page) is it clear now or what?

Comment: As far as I can understand you want to have a dropdown menu listing all your pages, and if the user click on it, her/his browser should navigate to that page. Is that correct?

Comment: yeah correct but i mean  i want this menu appear in all pages

Comment: put the code in the master page

Comment: AH, now I understand. But I see someone has already answered this question. @speciallife

Comment: yeah right but still there is a missing point for me i need to understand it , it is how to make this menu fixed in all page do i need to write the code of menu in all pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need JS for this. There are many solution for this you just did not used the right keywords. Try search for: *horizontal drop down menu css*

The first step is to create a nested ul-li-ul-li structure:

```
<ul id="coolMenu">
    <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mauricii</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Periher</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Hellenico</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Genere</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Indulgentia</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Tyrio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Quicumque</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then apply a few CSS rules.

```
#coolMenu,
#coolMenu ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#coolMenu {
    float: left;
}
#coolMenu > li {
    float: left;
}
#coolMenu li a {
display: block;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#coolMenu ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
z-index: 999;
}
#coolMenu ul li a {
    width: 80px;
}
#coolMenu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Further code: http://www.cssnewbie.com/horizontal-dropdown-menus/

Other solution: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/centered-dropdown-menus

Comment: good thnx for that but how to make this menu fixed at the top of page while navigating among links and know which item is active now

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786511/how-to-fix-a-div-to-top-of-page-with-css-only

Comment: Thnx Mr @Peter Kiss i will try your solution and i think it will solve my problem ,My regards :)