# How do I get my navbar fixed to the top?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I cant seem to get my navbar fixed to the top. It looks like the position: fixed is being obstructed by another element, possibly one of the pseudo-elements, I am not sure.

Also, ever since I decided to apply the background color to the whole nav_wrapper, my border radius for the sub menu disappeared for some reason.

HTML:

```
<!-- NAV -->
<div class="nav_wrapper">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Calandar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
        <ul class="sub_nav1">
            <li class="the_pastor"><a href="#">The Pastor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
            <li class="about"><a href="#">About Byzantines</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Mass Times</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav_wrapper ul {
display: block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
font-size: 0;
/* remove whitespace */
min-width: 5px;
background-color: #993300;
}

.nav_wrapper ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  /* font-size reset */
}
/* hides the submenu by default */

.nav_wrapper ul ul {
  display: none;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
/* makes the sub menu appear on hover over list element */

.nav_wrapper ul li:hover > .sub_nav1 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
/* lists the list items on top of one another */

.nav_wrapper ul .sub_nav1 li {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav_wrapper ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px;
}
.nav_wrapper li a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
/* Dropdown Menu arrow */

.nav_wrapper ul> li > a:after {
  content: '\25BE';
  line-height: 0;
}
.nav_wrapper ul li > a:only-child:after {
  content: '';
}

/* BORDER RADIUS'S */

.nav_wrapper ul ul .the_pastor {
border-top-left-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}

.nav_wrapper ul ul .about {
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
}
```

Comment: how are you trying to fix it to the top? you want a sticky header?

Comment: unfortunately I can't find "position:fixed" in your css. Also, to get border-radius to work, you also need to specify other border properties like border width and color. Without border width, border radius won't take effect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix a Div to top of page with CSS only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786511/how-to-fix-a-div-to-top-of-page-with-css-only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these two blocks to your css:
1. You need to position the outer block, not your ul inside it.
2. Put your radius on your sub ul, not the li inside it.

```
.nav_wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.sub_nav1 {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
}
```

Comment: worked perfectly, I did not know I had to position the container! Thanks!

Comment: Andy, welcome to SO! :) Please, take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to earn your first shiny badge ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:fixed` to `.nav_wrapper` itself, instead of it's children elements.

Comment: that did not work at all

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.nav_wrapper {
    line-height: 30px; //to taste
    height: 34px;//to taste
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
     z-index: 98;
}
```

Comment: Put the inner elements in nav_wrapper with 100% width and position fixed too.