# Fix a region on top of page like breadcrumb. (ORACLE-APEX)

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I want to fix a Static Region on top of the page below the breadcrumb bar so that when I scroll down the page, the static region is floating along with the breadcrumb bar. 
One solution for this is to define static region within the breadcumb region. But, I want this to be a separate region in itself.

Answer (score 1):

Initially, I wanted to advise you to use floating CSS class as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786511/how-to-fix-a-div-to-top-of-page-with-css-only)
But then I found that any item (region or otherwise) you place in the breadcrumbs *section* is set to be floating by default. Therefore, you do not have to add the region inside the breadcrumb region. You can add it outside, but within the breadcrubms section as illustrated betlow:

[image]

This is the result:
[image]

**UPDATE**
You could use body section to add floating region that allows you to add items side by side out of the box. But achieving that is a little bit troublesome. Your best bet, in my opinion, is manipulate the items in the breadcrumbs section. I achieved that as follows:

- Added three number fields to the region in the breadcrumbs section.
- Added the following CSS class to my page:

  [image]
- For each of the fields items, I applied the CSS class:

  [image]
- The result is floating region with items inside side by side

  [image]

Comment: I tried this solution but it has one problem due to column span. In the breadcrumb region, it won't let you add two items side by side. I want to add items side by side in the item section of the floating region.

Comment: @TirambadShiwakoti See my updated answer addressing your issue

Answer (score 0):

This seems overengineered. Can't you just put the region in the breadcrumb bar location?
https://community.oracle.com/message/14213035